# Postgres jsonb and query

Tags: sql, postgresql, jsonb

I have a postgres database. Inside "match" table I store a JSONB like this one, inside "when" column:

```
{{"end": "2017-01-04T17:22:13.311693Z", "start": "2017-01-04T16:22:13.311693Z"}, {"end": "2017-01-04T17:22:13.311693Z", "start": "2017-01-04T16:22:13.311693Z"}}
```

and it works like a list of object storing a start time and an end time.
Now i want to query all matches that are not past. How can i do that? Is it possible to compare a single "start" value with the current data?

Comment: Missing, helpful info: Your Postgres version; table definition (`CREATE TABLE` statement showing data types & constraints; what you have so far (even if it's not working); desired example result.

Comment: Postgres version: 9.6.2, table definition is not crucial here because it's a sample for a more complex scenario. "when" column is just defined as {:array, :map} in elixir (Ecto migration), and stored as jsonb in my database. Desired result: SELECT * FROM Matches WHERE at least one "end" field inside json array is > than current utc datetime

Comment: Your sample value isn't legal JSON. Is it supposed to be an array? So `'[{"end": "...", "start": "..."}, {...}]'`?

Comment: It gets decoded as array of objects, so i think that it's correct

Comment: You think? This isn't a matter of opinions. `ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type json`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at [this SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!17/bc0aa/1).

You can query into the jsonb using the `->>` operator. For dates/times, you'll need to convert the results in order to compare. This query returns only values with a future start:

```
SELECT when_col->>'start' FROM match
WHERE to_date(when_col->>'start','YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS') >= NOW();
```

Note that the JSON you gave above was malformed. I broke it out into separate rows in the fiddle:

```
CREATE TABLE match
(
  when_col jsonb
 );

 INSERT INTO match (when_col) VALUES ('{"end": "2017-01-04T17:22:13.311693Z", "start": "2017-01-04T16:22:13.311693Z"}');
 INSERT INTO match (when_col) VALUES ('{"end": "2017-02-04T17:22:13.311693Z", "start": "2017-02-04T16:22:13.311693Z"}');
 INSERT INTO match (when_col) VALUES ('{"end": "2019-02-04T17:22:13.311693Z", "start": "2019-02-04T16:22:13.311693Z"}');
 INSERT INTO match (when_col) VALUES ('{"end": "2029-02-04T17:22:13.311693Z", "start": "2029-02-04T16:22:13.311693Z"}');
```